# Переход на активити из класса

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть класс(допустим main) в нем есть функция которая должна отправлять нас на другую активити, я пробовал `val i = Intent(this, активити_на_которую_переходим::class.java)`, но ругается на this. Можно ли как то подругому это реализоать?

Comment: `this` это должен быть `Context` который можно получить так `requireContext()` если это фрагмент или от какой-то view `View.getContext()`, вобщем как получить `Context`  зависит от класса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В параметры Intent-а нужно передавать экземпляр класса Context.

Если ваша класс не реализует Context - то this естественно не подойдет. Вы можете в ваш класс передать Context из той активити, в которой собственно класс создается.

Но я не уверен, что вы вообще мыслите в правильном направлении. Другие активити зачастую открывать должны классы, реализующие Context или какие-то роутеры в которые вынесена логика создания активити. Но без кода трудно более точно дать вам рекомендацию.